# Image processing: Minimizing laplacian norm with boundary conditions

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to minimize this function (by A):

argmin_A (||L(A)||^2 + a||A-B||^2*)

where:

- A is a MxN image L is the Laplacian Operator
- ||.|| is the usual norm (Frobrenius)
- a is a weight parameter
- B is a matrix of size (M+2*k)xN
  where k is an integer parameter.
- (*) indicates that **we just consider the pixels in the boundary** (we want to preserve in A the pixels in the boundary of B).

Maybe the problem has a trivial solution, but I'm absolutely blocked.

If you need more details, it's (4) equation in this [paper](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/papers/deconvolution_boundary_iccp08.pdf).

I will be very grateful for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking carefully at that paper, [gridfit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit) does essentially that, although it does not employ the boundary conditions you ask for. You could certainly write what you want however, or you could simply apply a weight to the boundary points. This is not a difficult problem, but in order to solve it efficiently, you would want to employ the sparse matrix capabilities of MATLAB.